# AmazonS3 multipart uploading

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, uploading

I have used multi part uploading for uploading image to Amazon S3 as mentioned in [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/llJavaUploadFile.html).

But then the files uploaded can be access directly without access key or anything. Tested using the remote URL which is got from response for a particular file. 
Is there any way to restrict access to uploaded file?
Also is there a way to change the upload URL here, If I want to add a folder and the the file?

Comment: You need to define access for folder in Amazon s3 bucket, so can be restricted

Comment: @RajuSharma, that statement is not correct.  **S3 buckets and objects are secure and inaccessible by default**.  If an object can be unexpectedly be downloaded anonymously, then a mistake has been made by the user, either during the upload or on the bucket policy or ACLs. Your comment implies that "folders" are somehow needed for security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can create folder by using below method.

```
     AmazonS3 amazons3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());
     public void createFolder(String bucketName, String folderName)
        {
            try
            {

                        ObjectMetadata objectMetaData = new ObjectMetadata();
                        objectMetaData.setContentLength(0);
                        InputStream emptyContent = new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[0]);
                        amazons3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, folderName + "/", emptyContent, objectMetaData));
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                LOGGER.error("Exception In Create Folder", exception);
            }

        }
```

Access rights you can use policy and it will apply on specific to your bucket,Please go through below link
You can allow specific IP to access.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html

Comment: got a exception com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Read timed out .

Comment: instead of  AmazonS3 amazons3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new ProfileCredentialsProvider()); use your AmazonS3 Client Object.

Comment: ya i did that. i am using multipart uploading. so will the request keyName change to foldername + "/" +key; ?
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/llJavaUploadFile.html

Comment: Yeah it will change while uploading you have to use folderName+"/"+Key

Comment: this worked tnx man, but the file path returned after uploading is like
https://amazonexample.com/5628%2F1035d02b35beec44c08a39c15b95897d

5628 is folder and it comes as % idk y

Comment: no problem. found a solution. just had to decode the url for  %2F

Answer (score 1):

For managing access to your file, you will need to follow the instructions here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-access-control.html

It is covered in more detail here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/intro-managing-access-s3-resources.html

Comment: thnx for the help. this helped.

Comment: adding this did the job. request.setCannedACL(CannedAccessControlList.AuthenticatedRead);